# Set minPointLength for one of two series in highchart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I have two series of data in my highchart and want to use "minPointLength" for only one of them. Is this possible to set? My series contains only: name, color and data. My chartconfig looks like this:

```
const chartConfig = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
    dashStyle: 'ShortDash',
  },
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  xAxis: {
    padding: 0,
    plotLines: [{
      dashStyle: 'shortDash',
    }],
  },
  yAxis: {
    opposite: true,
    title: {
      text: '',
    },
    gridLineDashStyle: 'dash',
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      borderRadiusTopLeft: 32,
      borderRadiusTopRight: 32,
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        crop: false,
        overflow: 'none',
      },
      enableMouseTracking: false,
    },
    series: {
      pointWidth: 24,
      minPointLength: 3,
    },
  },
};
```

What I want is to always show minimum height on one of the datasets. Even if the scale goes from 1 to 1 000 000, it supposed to be a little peak at the bottom if one of my columns shows 3 out of 1 000 000.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can set a `minPointLength` property individually for each series:

```
series: [{
    minPointLength: 80,
    data: [...]
}, {
    data: [...]
}]
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/19nc8jv6/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.minPointLength